# Update DateTime column in SQL Server through Python

Tags: python, sql-server

Please, I am trying to update a `datetime` column in a SQL Server database through Python. For example, the date is `'2020-01-22'` and when I update it through Python, in the database the column is updated to `'1905-06-21'`.

I tried using a `datetime` parameter as well as the T-SQL `CAST` command to convert from string to `datetime`, but the result is the same.

May you help me? Thanks.

That's the code:

```
date = '2020-01-22'

cursor.execute("UPDATE Tab3 SET DatRech = CONVERT(datetime, %s, 104)"  %date)
df = pd.read_sql_query('Select * from Tab3', conn)
```

Query result:

```
DatRech =  1905-06-21
```

But when I use:

```
cursor.execute("Update Tab3 set DatRech = CAST('22-01-2020' as datetime)")
```

or

```
cursor.execute("Update Tab3 set DatRech = GETDATE()")
```

it works.

Extra Information:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};' 
                       Server=LAPTOP-ON7O00M4\MSSQLSERVER02;'
                       Database=Teste;' 'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

SQL Version = Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: Please show us your code! After all- we cannot see nor read your screen, nor your mind ... you have to **show us** if we should have *any chance* of helping you!

Comment: Note that if you are passing the dates as strings the only two formats that aren't affected by the client's or the server's language settings are ISO8601 strings.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Apart from that `yyyy-MM-dd` is ***not*** unambiguous in SQL Server @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. Only `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` and `yyyyMMdd` are.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Not _all_ ISO8601 strings are.  But the two unambiguous strings are both ISO8601.

Comment: My guess is that you are not passing `2020-01-22` as text and SQL Server implicitly converts the integer expression `2020-01-22` as date - `select DATEADD(day, 2020-01-22, 0)` returns `1905-06-21 00:00:00.000`. Please, post your code.

Comment: Sounds like a likely answer, @Zhorov , which also strongly implies the OP is injecting their value, not parametrising it; an even **bigger** problem.

Comment: Hi everone, I've found the solution. I tried  d = '2022-01-23'
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE Tab3 SET DatRech=CONVERT(datetime, '{d}', 102)") and it worked. Thank you for your attention.